# nhibernate joinalias doesnt build right query

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I get `SqlException (The multi-part identifier "packageali1_.PackageID" could not be bound.)` whenever I try to execute this query (QueryOver):

```
var brandsFromBrandsInManufacturer2 =
  session.QueryOver<Brand>(() => brandAlias)
    .JoinAlias(brand => brand.Package, () => packageAlias)
    .Where(
       brand =>
       brand.ArtificialBrand == 0
     )
    .And(brand => packageAlias.PackageID
       .IsIn(branchPackagesProductGroupShortName.Keys))
    .Select(brand => brand.BrandName,
       brand => packageAlias.PackageID)
    List<object[]>();
```

It looks like I have error in my mappings:

```
public class PackageMap : ClassMap<Package>
{
    public PackageMap()
    {
        Table("Packages");
        Id(x => x.PackageID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Aggregated).CustomType<PackageAggregation>();
        References(x => x.DataEndPeriod, "DataEndPeriodID");
        References(x => x.Country, "CountryID");
        References(x => x.ProductGroup, "ProductGroupID");

        HasMany(x => x.PackageHierarchies).KeyColumns.Add("PackageId");
        HasMany(x => x.Brands).KeyColumns.Add("PackageId").Inverse();
    } 
}


public BrandMap()
    {
        Table("Brands");
        CompositeId().KeyProperty(x =>x.BrandId).KeyReference(x => x.Package, "PackageId");
        Map(x => x.BrandName);
        References(x => x.Manufacturer).Columns(x => x.ManufacturerId).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ArtificialBrand);
    }
```

but I can't find what is wrong. Only thing what I've found is fact, that `Brand` has classic ID key, but `Package` has composite key.

PS: SQL query from nHibernate is:

```
 SELECT this_.BrandName as y0_, packageali1_.PackageID as y1_ FROM CD.Brands this_ WHERE this_.ArtificialBrand = @p0 and packageali1_.PackageID in (...)
```

so as you can see, there is no JOIN.

Could someone point me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here would be to "work" directly with the Key property `Package`, instead of its alias. So, instead of `packageAlias.PackageID`, let's navigate there directly through the `brand.Package.PackageID`.

Also, if we've created so many aliases, let's use them

```
var brandsFromBrandsInManufacturer2 = session
    .QueryOver<Brand>(() => brandAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => brandAlias.Package, () => packageAlias) // use brandAlias
    .Where(() => brandAlias.ArtificialBrand == 0 )
    // no go to Package directly, not via packageAlias
    .And(() => brandAlias.Package.PackageID
       .IsIn(branchPackagesProductGroupShortName.Keys))
    // the same here, the brand.Package...
    .Select(brand => brand.BrandName,
       brand => brand.Package.PackageID)
    List<object[]>();
```

Well, the second line, is in fact redundant. so it could be like this:

```
var list = session
    .QueryOver<Brand>(() => brandAlias)
    .Where(() => brandAlias.ArtificialBrand == 0 )
    .And(() => brandAlias.Package.PackageID
       .IsIn(branchPackagesProductGroupShortName.Keys))
    .Select(brand => brand.BrandName,
            brand => brand.Package.PackageID)
    List<object[]>();
```